# Bring Camera on lock screen

Tags: android

I am new to android and wanted to do an experimental project on android unlocking applications and  I have am using this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision for detection. 
I want to get detection camera view on lock screen so that I can capture a frame and then later use it for verification but I don't seem to find any resources that can help me get detection activity on lock screen. I would be grateful if anyone can help. :)
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. You must implement your own lockscreen (like other lockscreen app)
2. In your own lockscreen you can put camera view and your logic to this view to detect screen unlock
3. (Optional) You should check current lock setting's user and ask user turn it off (so user only use your own solution)

Hope this help !